# curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the push function

Tags: bash, curl, sdk

you can help me with installing sdkman. When I enter the console `"curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash"`, nothing happens ...

I tried `"curl -sv "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash"`

```
Rebuilt URL to: https://get.sdkman.io/
Trying 159.89.187.78...
Connected to get.sdkman.io (159.89.187.78) port 443 (#0)
found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
found 597 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
ALPN, offering http/1.1
gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the push function.
Closing connection 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# host get.sdkman.io
get.sdkman.io has address 159.89.187.78
```

IP 159.89.187.78 is in Roscomnadzor blacklist.
You can check it:

https://blocklist.rkn.gov.ru/

Answer (score 0):

IF you are here for another solution that involves WSL and a change in the DNS nameserver and search domain enforced by your ISP. Here's the solution :

**Problem** : Same error as in the OP

```
  $ curl https://registry.terraform.io/
  curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the push function.
```

**Root Cause**: I'm using a WSL machine that takes all the DNS config from my ISP WIFI router (in Canada)

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 64.71.255.204
nameserver 64.71.255.198
nameserver 2607:f798:18:10:0:640:7125:5204
search phub.net.cable.rogers.com
```

**Solution:**
comment everything and add Google's nameservers

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
#search phub.net.cable.rogers.com
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.4.4.8
```

Don't forget to force the imutability of your resolv.conf after change .

```
sudo chattr -f +i etc/resolv.conf
```

**Test**

```
$ curl https://registry.terraform.io/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Terraform Registry</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    ...
    </noscript>
        </body>
</html>
```

cheers.